# My motorcycle's engine turns off while driving

Tags: engine, motorcycle, ignition, royal-enfield, thunderbird

I have a RE Thunderbird 350 and now-a-days sometimes my engine turns off while I am riding. Earlier, it used to happen once in a while when I used the Pass switch or the indicators.

From the last few days, the condition has become quite frequent and now the bike turns off in the middle of nowhere on its own. After which if I try to turn on any electrical switch, the ignition also goes off.

After keeping the bike idle for about a minute or so, the bike starts again.

Any idea what the problem might be would be of great help.

Comment: I am by far not a motorcycle expert, but what are the weather conditions like and do all electronics stop working (headlight, blinkers, dash etc)?

Comment: Did you do any investigation when it first started to occur, or just hoped it would go away?

Comment: @MindSwipe: It is quite hot and humid here. Yes, all the electronics stop working.
It is just like when you first enter the key and turn on the ignition, the odometer and RPM meter goes to the fullest and then come back as soon as I turn on any switch.
This happens randomly though, sometimes all the switches work fine, while sometimes they don't. I can't specifically figure out a pattern here.

Comment: @SolarMike: I did some investigation. I hoped it was some case of electrical faults so I removed all the electrical terminals one by one and then re-joined them, thinking this might have happened due to deposition of Carbon on the terminals, but that didn't work.
I will be taking the bike to a mechanic this weekend to have it corrected though.

Comment: My guess is a faulty battery or a faulty onboard computer (but as I said I'm far from a professional), I really hope it's the first because a faulty computer cost quite a bit more. Good that you're getting it looked at by a professional, this is very dangerous not only for you but also the other people on the road

Comment: I agree with @MindSwipe on battery or ecu probably. Would help to know the year of the bike as I'm not familiar with that one.

Answer (score 1):

The main culprits would be your Battery or alternator. Try checking you alternator and battery. Check if alternator is supplying the desired currrent to the battery to get charged. Also the check the battery voltage if it managing to dischage the desired amount of current while using the accessory.

Additionally give a look on to rectifier - it rearly fails. Just in case :)

if you do have any extra fittings such as aux lights, headlight bulb and horns not supplied by RE. Kindly remove from circuit.

What I hate with new bike design is that all the bike electronics heavily depend on battery. If battery fails you are stranded, Unlike old bike you cant event push start it

Comment: And don't rule out that it's BOTH the battery and charging system. A poor charging system can also wreck the battery over time. Replacing the battery will fix it temporarily but you will just have the same problem again down the road.